# How to solve c = cov(x, y, rowvar) RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice error in python 3.8?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, recommendation-engine, python-3.8

I am following a tutorial to build a recommendation system in python from the below link. I'm using python 3.8 to build it.

https://stackabuse.com/creating-a-simple-recommender-system-in-python-using-pandas/

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

ratings_data = pd.read_csv("E:/Python/ml-latest-small//ratings.csv")
ratings_data.head()

movie_names = pd.read_csv("E:/Python/ml-latest-small//movies.csv")  
movie_names.head()

movie_data = pd.merge(ratings_data, movie_names, on='movieId')
movie_data.head()


movie_data.groupby('title')['rating'].mean().head()

movie_data.groupby('title')['rating'].mean().sort_values(ascending=False).head() 

movie_data.groupby('title')['rating'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).head()

ratings_mean_count = pd.DataFrame(movie_data.groupby('title')['rating'].mean())
ratings_mean_count['rating_counts'] = pd.DataFrame(movie_data.groupby('title')['rating'].count())
ratings_mean_count.head()

user_movie_rating = movie_data.pivot_table(index='userId', columns='title', values='rating')
user_movie_rating.head()

forrest_gump_ratings = user_movie_rating['Forrest Gump (1994)']
forrest_gump_ratings.head()

movies_like_forest_gump = user_movie_rating.corrwith(forrest_gump_ratings)

corr_forrest_gump = pd.DataFrame(movies_like_forest_gump, columns=['Correlation'])  
corr_forrest_gump.dropna(inplace=True)  
corr_forrest_gump.head()
```

I am getting the following error due to this line.

**movies_like_forest_gump = user_movie_rating.corrwith(forrest_gump_ratings)**

[image]

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that it's not possible to compute a Pearson correlation (the default correlation method for `corrwith`) between Forrest Gump and movie X unless there are at least 2 users that have rated both Forrest Gump and movie X. You get a warning because the data most likely doesn't satisfy that condition for all movies.

In practical terms, you can do some filtering to the ratings matrix:

- Remove users that have not rated Forrest Gump.

  ```
  user_movie_rating = user_movie_rating[user_movie_rating.get('Forrest Gump (1994)').notnull()]
  ```
- Remove movies that don't have at least 2 ratings. After this, all movies will have at least 2 ratings from users that have also rated Forrest Gump, because after the previous step everyone has rated Forrest Gump.

  ```
  user_movie_rating = user_movie_rating.dropna(axis='columns', thresh=2)
  ```